# Why do I keep getting NaN as output instead of correct data?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please point out my mistakes. I keep getting `nan` as output.

```
  function order() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name");
      var numOfCakeDonuts = document.getElementById("numOfCakeDonuts").valueAsNumber;
      var numOfGlazedDonuts = document.getElementById("numOfCakeDonuts").valueAsNumber;
      var time = document.getElementById("time").valueAsNumber;
      const taxrate = 0.14;
      const donutPrice = 0.50;
      var subTotal = (numOfCakeDonuts + numOfGlazedDonuts) * donutPrice;
      var tax = subTotal * taxrate;
      var total = subTotal + tax;
      document.getElementById("sub").value = subTotal.toFixed(3);
      document.getElementById("tax").value = tax.toFixed(3);
      document.getElementById("total").value = total.toFixed(3);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for providing your JS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's difficult to reproduce this without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Consider using a debugger to inspect the results of each step.

Comment: Do your input fields contain values? Every used variable in your code is a number, if each input has some numeric (also non-empty) value.

Comment: Did you find the problem Abhinav? What was it?

Answer (score 1):

## Mis-assignment

Your variable `numOfGlazedDonuts` is being assigned the `valueAsNumber` of element with `id=numOfCakeDonuts` for a start.

Comment: But that wouldn't cause the `NaN` thing the OP asked about, it just means the calculation is effectively (cake + cake) rather than (cake + glazed).

Comment: @nnnnnn - Or would it? Without seeing more code, as Obsidian Age suggested, we're in the dark. With mis-assignment may come a lot of other simple errors, that could even be `undefined` in arithmetic.

Comment: If the problem is with the value of the `#numOfCakeDonuts` element then the OP's code would not work even if the typo you identified is fixed. So I stand by my statement that although this is definitely *a* problem, it is not *the* problem.

Comment: @nnnnnn - `(undefined + undefined) * 0.5;` = `NaN`

Comment: Yes. So fixing the typo won't in any way help with the `NaN`.

Comment: `NaN.toFixed(3);` = `"NaN"` -- if the coder makes a mistake getting elements by id, it is possible, if not likely, that they made exactly that mistake and are in fact doing math with `undefined`.